# C++ vectorization of user defined type

Tags: c++, vectorization

Say I am writing a modular arithmetic type, after each arithmetic operation a mod P operation (% P) is applied.

I would like the new type to be usable with STL's algorithms, as well as execution policies.

It seems that the `par` policy should work, but what about `unseq` vectorization? Is it possible to integrate vectorization capabilities of the standard library with a custom numeric type?

How would I add the numeric traits to the custom type?

BTW, I know that there are modular arithmetic libraries. This is an exercise with modern C++.

Answer (score 1):

You're still going to rely on template instantiation followed by compilation. `unseq` vectorization should come from the compiler noticing that there can't be aliasing, allowing it to choose SIMD instructions. That means you're not writing the SIMD instructions manually.

However, you should give the compiler a fair chance to see all the operations together. If your `operator+` is only seen by the linker, it would be compiled as a scalar operation . That means you'll need to make all the operations `inline` so the compiler can combine multiple calls.

Comment: thanks. are you familiar with a non-trivial example which is translated to SIMD instructions? can you share a link?

Comment: @hanan: I've seen Visual Studio do so even in the absence of `unseq`; I suddenly found a vectorized `expf` in my profiling results. The capability has been there for a while.